# How to display texts from JavaScript multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, string, button

I'm familiar with using ID's to help display your JavaScript string text onto your HTML webpage like so:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onClick = "display()">Press Me</button>
<p id = "text"></p>

<script>

function display() {
var string = "hello";
var message = document.getElementById("text");
message.innerHTML = string;      
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But what if I wanted to display "hello" multiple times by the press of the button? I don't want to keep adding id's the same way I did "text" to appear. Is there anyway I could simply print out the text once you press the button for however many times you'd like in **vanilla** JavaScript?

Also, I am aware of "`repeat()`" but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, If I press one time it'll show hello, if I press another time It will show another hello bellow the first one and etc?

Comment: Instead of `message.innerHTML = string;`, I would do like: `message.textContent += string+'<br />';`. I just used `.textContent` so HTML parsing is not an issue. It's the `+=` that you need.

Comment: @FernandoZamperin correct, although it doesn't necessarily have to be on the next line. I was just curious on how I'd like to have the string repeat multiple times by the click of the button.

Comment: @StackSlave Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what if I wanted to display "hello" multiple times by the press of
> the button?

It's enough to change this line:

```
message.innerHTML = string;
```

to:

```
message.innerHTML += string;   // add at the end....
```

```html
<button onClick = "display()">Press Me</button>
<p id = "text"></p>

<script>

    function display() {
        var string = "hello ";
        var message = document.getElementById("text");
        message.innerHTML += string;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't aware the addition assignment operator managed to do that